# Sum of digits of the $100$ th power of a continuous function in single variable

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

> Let $f(x)$  be a continuous function such that $f(x) > 0$ for all
>   non-negative $x$
>
> And,
>
> $$ (f(x))^{101}  =  1 + \int_{0}^x f(t)dt $$
>
> Then,
>
> $$ (f(101))^{100} = 100A+10B+C $$
>
> Where $A,B,C$  are integers from $[0,9]$  . So, $ A + B + C = ?$

I've tried using Newton-Leibneitz theorem on the initial statement but all I ended up at was that $f(101)$ is an integral multiple of $101$ .
I do not know how to proceed beyond that.

Comment: Is $ABC$ the decimals, or $A \times B \times C$?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough.
ABC is the decimal expression,as in, A*100 + B*10 +C

Comment: Is my edit OK for you?

Comment: Yes,its ok, thank you.

Comment: $f(101)$ clearly cannot be an integer multiple of $101$, as for any positive integer multiple $m=101n$ you have $m^{100} > 999$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$(f(0))^{101}=1+\int_{0}^{0}f(t)\mathrm{d}t  \implies (f(0))^{100}=1$$

Differentiating each side of  $$ (f(x))^{101}  =  1 + \int_{0}^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t $$ with respect to $x$ gives us that $$101(f(x))^{100}f'(x)=f(x) \iff (f(x))^{99}f'(x)=\frac{1}{101} \tag{1}$$
Note that $$g(x)=(f(x))^{100}\Rightarrow g'(x)=\frac{100}{101}  \Rightarrow g(x)=\frac{100}{101}x+C$$

From $(1)$. Thus, we have that $(f(x))^{100}=\frac{100}{101}x+1$ from the fact that $(f(0))^{100}=1$.

So, since the value is $101$, the answer is $2$.

Comment: Aah,I got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

differentiating both sides you get,

$101 f(x)^{100} f'(x) = f(x)$

i.e $f(x)^{99} f'(x) = \frac{1}{101}$

so integrating both sides we get

$f(x)^{100} = \frac{100}{101}x + c$ where $c$ is some constant

now $f(0) = 1$ from  the initial equation. hence $c = 1 $

Now put $x=101$ to get $f(101)^{100} = 101$